# Nexus 4 on cm 13 nightly - application cannot download files

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, download-manager, cyanogenmod

I have recently downloaded cm 13 and flashed it on Nexus 4. Since then none of my applications can download any files. Google apps can do that though.

I have tried to capture the relevant debug info from adb:

```
03-23 14:39:57.576 717-717/system_process W/PackageManager: Permission android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION from package com.android.providers.downloads in an unknown group android.permission-group.NETWORK
03-23 14:40:12.658 717-717/system_process W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x3849be45)
03-23 14:40:12.658 717-717/system_process W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x3849be45)
03-23 14:40:13.419 717-1141/system_process W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x38c9be45)
03-23 14:40:13.419 717-1141/system_process W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x38c9be45)
03-23 14:42:03.712 2170-2232/com.android.nfc D/NfcService: checking on firmware download
03-23 14:42:06.057 659-659/? E/kickstart: Successfully downloaded files from target 
03-23 14:42:06.743 717-2057/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2727:android.process.media/u0a9 for broadcast com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadReceiver
03-23 14:42:16.443 3255-3274/? I/MessagingAppDataModel: Fixup: Send failed - 0 Download failed - 0
03-23 14:43:36.458 659-659/? E/kickstart: Successfully downloaded files from target 
03-23 14:44:25.562 2727-2752/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: Path appears to be invalid: /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.coolapk.market-6.4.0-1603173.apk
03-23 14:44:25.707 2727-4566/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Starting
03-23 14:44:26.198 2727-4566/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [1] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:44:26.199 2727-4566/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:45:09.370 2727-4758/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Starting
03-23 14:45:12.006 2727-4758/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [1] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:45:12.007 2727-4758/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:45:37.961 2059-2059/com.android.systemui D/StatusBar: Clicked on content of 0|com.android.providers.downloads|0|1:com.android.browser|10009
03-23 14:45:38.055 717-2014/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW_DOWNLOADS flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.providers.downloads.ui/.DownloadList} from uid 10025 on display 0
03-23 14:45:38.115 2727-2727/android.process.media W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/DownloadProviderUi/lib/arm
03-23 14:45:38.146 717-2014/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.provider.action.MANAGE_ROOT dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/root/downloads cmp=com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity} from uid 10009 on display 0
03-23 14:45:55.276 2727-2868/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: Path appears to be invalid: /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.coolapk.market-6.4.0-1603173.apk
03-23 14:45:55.383 2727-5648/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Starting
03-23 14:45:55.773 2727-5648/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [2] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:45:55.776 2727-5648/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:47:08.190 2727-6824/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Starting
03-23 14:47:08.192 2727-6825/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Starting
03-23 14:47:08.420 2727-6825/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [2] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:47:08.420 2727-6825/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:47:08.601 2727-6824/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [1] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:47:08.615 2727-6824/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:48:21.289 2727-7951/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Starting
03-23 14:48:24.624 2727-7951/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [2] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-23 14:48:24.629 2727-7951/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
03-23 14:50:30.886 2727-9818/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Starting
03-23 14:50:35.682 2727-9818/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [1] Stop requested with status 403: Unhandled HTTP response: 403 Forbidden
03-23 14:50:35.683 2727-9818/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [1] Finished with status 403
03-23 14:52:10.358 2727-11049/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Starting
03-23 14:52:10.911 2727-11049/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [2] Stop requested with status 403: Unhandled HTTP response: 403 Forbidden
03-23 14:52:10.911 2727-11049/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [2] Finished with status 403
03-23 14:57:23.790 659-659/? E/kickstart: Successfully downloaded files from target 
03-23 14:57:24.879 659-659/? E/kickstart: Successfully downloaded files from target
```

Any possible fix?

*Edit: Similar problems(practically the same errors) exist on CM 12.1 latest snapshot and Slimkat (4.4 builds). As for the slimkat build, it has been used for over a year with no problem. Now it happens out of the blue.*

Comment: Yes - contact the developer or get on a stable build :) Not much to do here for us - check [Recommendation for questions pertaining to a problem specific to a nightly build of a ROM](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/recommendation-for-questions-pertaining-to-a-problem-specific-to-a-nightly-build)

Comment: I have actually tried installing other aosp roms and they seems to have the same problem on my nexus. What confusing is though, downloading worked on the same build previously and now it breaks down all of a sudden. I have completely no idea how to even trace what caused this permission problem.

Comment: That's the risk of nightly build; you won't know what will break/be fixed. However, you said that it also happened on other AOSP ROMs, could you [edit] and put some details? IMHO, this post is considerably better than what we usually received related to nightly build. However, there's no guarantee that we can help solving this issue as end-user.

Comment: Edited as to the request of @AndrewT.

Comment: Reading from the LogCat, I found [AOSP Issue Tracker #195153](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195153) that says "*Apps that use the DownloadManager, targetSdkVersion <23, and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will experience this problem.*". Can you try to download using Chrome, or FireFox? Or else, may I know what apps are you using to download?

Comment: Oh. Turned out that I used root to recover my storage files and locked the files from not-root users. Problem fixed by chown-ing. Sorry for troubling you guys : )

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I used root to copy files onto the SD card directory (/storage/emulated/0), locking out non-root users.

`chown -R media_rw:media_rw /sdcard/*` in recovery fixed the problem. (Note that sdcard mount point can be different in different recoveries. I use TWRP)

Silly me :P

Comment: If this is the final answer, make sure to mark it as the accepted one and therefore close the thread :)

Answer (score 0):

`chown -R 1023:1023 /sdcard` [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144375/does-the-android-operating-system-have-files-like-etc-passwd-etc-shadow-and/#5144422) even shorter

I would also give `chmod -R 770 /sdcard` for [completeness](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67039074&postcount=105)